# What does it mean to have a "file name with NULL bytes in serialized instances"?

Tags: file-upload

I was browsing [this page](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/UbuntuWeeklyNewsletter/Issue343#Updates_and_Security_for_10.04.2C_12.04.2C_12.10.2C_13.04_and_13.10), which redirected me to [this](https://lists.ubuntu.com/archives/ubuntu-security-announce/2013-November/002317.html) vulnerability because I'm a Java developer and I'm aware of the affected library.

Basically the vulnerability says:

> It was discovered that Apache Commons FileUpload incorrectly handled
>   file names with NULL bytes in serialized instances. An attacker could
>   use this issue to possibly write to arbitrary files.

I just wan't to know what does this statement mean ?

> ...file names with NULL bytes in serialized instances.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

A null byte is a byte with the value zero, i.e. 0x00 in hex.

There have been security vulnerabilities related to null bytes. These occur because C uses null bytes as a string terminator. Other languages (Java, PHP, etc.) don't have a string terminator; they store the length of every string separately.

Now, consider a Java web application that accepts file uploads. Perhaps we want to let users upload `.jpg` files, but nothing else. In fact, if a user can upload a `.jsp` file, this will be a serious security vulnerability.

What a hacker might try is to upload `hack.jsp<NUL>.jpg`. Let's think about how this will be processed. First, Java will look at the file name, see it ends in `.jpg` and allow the upload. It then calls the operating system library, which is written in C. C sees the `<NUL>` character as the string terminator, so it saves the file as `hack.jsp`.

Many languages fix this by explicitly disallowing `<NUL>` bytes in file names. I know Python and PHP do this. However, if your language does not do this for you, you must do it yourself. More information - [OWASP: Null-Byte Injection](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/OWASP_Periodic_Table_of_Vulnerabilities_-_Null_Byte_Injection)

I don't know how exactly "serialised instances" is related to this, but I think this gives you some idea what's going on.

Comment: Is `serialized instances` a technical term ? Or does it mean what it says ? (i.e. serialized bytes !)

Answer (score 6):

Every character has a numeric value as dictated by the corresponding character set. So, for example, typically `A` is `65` and `a` is `97`. But if the number is `0`, then it's not really a character, it's a "null"; which basically means *not a character*.

In C and C++, this "null" character is used to mean the end of a string. So "HELLO" is stored like this:

```
 H   E   L   L   O  
72  69  76  76  79  00
```

The `00` on the end says "stop here". But not all frameworks use C-strings and their "null terminator" format; in fact most do not. Instead, the length of the string is stored up front and the actual contents can contain anything, including these *null* characters -- characters whose numeric value is `0`.

So in this instance, if the name contains one of these *null* characters, most of the code won't mind; *null* bytes are allowed. But when the name makes it to FileUpload code, that *null* ends up causing some confusion. Some of the code thinks that the name *ends* with the *null* byte, while other bits think that the *null* byte is just another letter. That confusion, where two bits of code don't agree on what the name actually is, then leads to a security vulnerability.